# My jest tests run fine separately but fail when run all routes together

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm making an API using TypeScript, node.
I'm using jest to make some tests

I have two different routes, "/users" and "/authentication", when I run one route at a time it runs ok, but when I run all tests together one of my tests returns me a 500 status code.

I'm running it in node v16.17.0

jest: v29.3.1

When I run `$npm run test users`

[image: /users tests result in terminal]

When I run `$npm run test authentication`

[image: /authentication tests result in terminal]

When I run `$npm run test`

[image: all tests result in terminal]

Thats my test scipts:
`"test:load-envs": "dotenv -e .env.test", "test": "npm run test:load-envs npx jest",`

I've tested it manually throught thunderClient and the error case runs fine...

On thunderClient trying to emulate the error:

[image: running the exacly same route with the same parameters]

I searched for someone with a similar error but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I can ignore this since it's a personal project, but I really would like to know how to solve it

Comment: Let's update your test or production code to fix that issue.

Comment: I don't think it is the code... I think it is some jest config... But I don't know what i need to change... I need to study jest configuration a little bit more...

Comment: It's difficult to determine the issue without seeing your code. This often suggests that there is some persistent data associated with the code you are testing that is not being properly reset. I highly doubt that it is the jest setup, as then more people would be running into the same issue.